# Cannot open graphical application through command line?

Tags: bash, fedora

I am having trouble opening graphical applications in linux (Sublime Text 2 in this case) through the terminal. I am using Fedora 17. I get this error for other graphical applications that I try to open up through the command line as well.

```
[root@computer djproject]# sublime settings.py
No protocol specified

(sublime:4202): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display: :0
```

Also, I get the same type of error when I try to do:

```
sudo sublime
```

Note in the command above I was logged in as a regular user without root access. Also 'sublime' is mapped to Sublime Text 2, and I have tested it before in other scenarios, so it is not the problem. Also, I have set this particular user up as a valid *sudoer* and the sudo command also works in other cases.

While researching the problem [I came across many similar cases with no clear solution.
The following link has a user with a similar problem](https://superuser.com/questions/310197/how-do-i-fix-a-cannot-open-display-error-when-opening-an-x-program-after-sshi) (although using ssh and on Ubuntu, rather than local and Fedora in my case).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: are you logged into the TTY (the whole screen is black and there is no gui open, possibly accessed by ctrl+alt+F1)? or a terminal emulator like `gnome-terminal` or `xterm`?

Comment: What does `echo $DISPLAY` returns?

Comment: I have tried gnome-terminal as well as terminator. echo $DISPLAY returns :0

Comment: Are you running the application as the same user who runs the X server?

Comment: This seems [off-topic for Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions). You might want to ask about this on [Unix.SE](http://unix.stackexchange.com) or [Super User](http://superuser.com) (but search for it there first!).

Answer (score 1):

I spent quite a lot of time trying to figure this problem out, and came across this thread as I found a fix. 
My problem was simply that I was running my commands from within the byobu session. I opened a new terminal tab and successfully ran the same commands.

Comment: Yes! I experienced the same problem with I tried to issue command from within tmux, but if I am outside tmux, SublimeText opens just fine

Answer (score 0):

Since `DISPLAY` is being defined, this may be a problem with permissions. How are you starting X? (As far as I know normally X is started by root and when you login you are granted access such that these issues don't occur, unless you're running `sudo` from a different account than the one you're logged into X with.)

You need to provide the correct 'cookie' file to access the session (simply being root isn't enough to get in).  For users this is normally `~/.Xauthority`, so executing `xauth merge /home/<user>/.Xauthority` should do the trick.

Alternatively have you tried `gksu`?

Comment: ~/.Xauthority does not exist on my machine. I looked into it more and couldn't find .Xauthority anywhere, although I may not be checking all of the correct places - I am on Fedora 17 if the distro matters. gksu is not recognized as a command.

Comment: @Joker I'm not on Fedora so cannot test myself but try `gksudo` or `beesu` (you'll need the beesu package installed). The Xauthority file for a given user may only exist when that user is logged into X, so ensure you're checking when that user is logged in.Also, you may have the `XAUTHORITY` environment variable defined, which will contain the location to the Xauthority (this overrides the default `~/.Xauthority`).

Answer (score 0):

I actually needed this (run an X application from CLI with a different user), and valid workarround is to SSH -X:

user1 owns X
user2 is the second user that wants to run an X program from CLI, in this example, eclipse ide

```
user1:~$ ssh -X user2@localhost
The authenticity of host 'localhost (127.0.0.1)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is 
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Permanently added 'localhost' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
user2@localhost's password: 
Welcome to Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.13.0-44-generic x86_64)

user2:~$ 
user2:~$ /opt/eclipse/eclipse
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is 5 years old post, but I spend much time to solve issue like this on installation of **Renderman of Pixar**. Then I like to send my solution that maybe **helps someone else**

The problem is because of this "sudoer (here `root`) has no access to graphical space". (I don't know it is always or sometimes. I faced this issue on Ubuntu 16.04)

Doing the following solved my issue:

first, start `Terminal` as graphical user, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
then, execute these lines

```
$ unset XAUTHORITY
$ xhost add $DISPLAY . 123f
$ xhost +local:all
$ sudo xclock # or any graphical program needs sudoer
```

Let me know your feedbacks